# Cannot upload a PIC using AFNetworking

Tags: file-upload, afnetworking

I can upload PIC in Postman, and in swagger. I need to set @{@"Content-Type": @"multipart/form-data"} in Header.
But in OC programm, it's some errors. Help!!

```
  NSString *urlString =@"http://192.168.1.1/upload";
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"camp.jpg"];
  NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
  NSLog(@"上传图片的样子：%@", imageData);

  NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"file":@"camp.jpg"};

   AFHTTPSessionManager *manager1 = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
   manager1.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];   // 请求JSON格式
   manager1.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]; // 响应JSON格式
manager1.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8", nil];
```

[manager1 POST:urlString parameters:parameters headers:@{@"Content-Type": @"multipart/form-data"} constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id  _Nonnull formData) {

```
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"camp.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
 
} progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    
    NSLog(@"上传成功：%@", responseObject);

    
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    
    NSLog(@"上传失败：%@", error);
}];
```

and the error is:

Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500), NSUnderlyingError=0x2833b5e90 {Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/json" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/json, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.sample.com:18081/camping/file/v1/pic/upload, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data={length = 347, bytes = 0x7b227469 6d657374 616d7022 3a223230 ... 75706c6f 6164227d }, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x283cb67c0> { URL: http://192.168.1.1/upload } { Status Code: 500, Headers {
Connection =     (
close
);
"Content-Type" =     (
"application/json;charset=UTF-8"
);
Date =     (
"Tue, 23 Nov 2021 0
2021-11-23 11:10:20.853300+0800 Campingsitedemo[76232:4244771] [UICollectionViewRecursion] cv == 0x105a5f400 Disabling recursion trigger logging
2021-11-23 11:10:51.172438+0800 Campingsitedemo[76232:4245042] [tcp] tcp_input [C10.1:2] flags=[R.] seq=2019602476, ack=0, win=64240 state=TIME_WAIT rcv_nxt=2019602983, snd_una=2071941654

Answer (score 0):

change to AFHTTPRequestSerializer

manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

it's ok now